# Restrict S3 object access to requests from a specific domain

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I have video files in S3 and a simple player that loads the files via an src attribute.

I want the videos to only be viewed through my site and not directly via the S3 URL (which might be visible in the source code of the page or accessible via right clicking)

Looking through the AWS docs it seems the only way i can do this via HTTP is to append a signature and expiration date to a query but this isn't sufficient.
Other access restrictions refer to AWS users.

How do i get around this or implement this server/client side?

Answer (score 11):

I think a Bucket Policy - which you can set up from the admin interface - will do this. There are some variations on the syntax (you can build your policy around a **deny** or an **allow** condition for instance) and filter on specific filenames, though I prefer to split media types into discrete buckets

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "Restrict based on HTTP referrer policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myprefix/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.mydomain.com/*",
                    "http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: thanks for this am i allowed to have multiple bucket policies or do i have to add this to my existing policy? where can i find out about adding a policy to an existing one?

Comment: I think it's one policy per bucket, but you can have multiple statements within a policy. easiest way to edit policies is either via the AWS admin console or something like http://s3browser.com/working-with-amazon-s3-bucket-policies.php

Comment: Any way to do the same thing for a Mobile App? i.e only if the request if from my Android Mobile App - S3 should allow GET - else not.

Comment: @Jasper - I'd probably ask that as a separate question just to get some visibility

Comment: @Offbeatmammal > Thats good advice, although over-zealous, well-meaning folks would immediately mark it as off-topic, not-a-programming-question n such :)

Comment: but then I can't score internet points for pointing you to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html and specifically the aws:UserAgent condition qualifier ;)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, can you explain more on how this can be done for a mobile app? I saw the link you shared, but not sure how UserAgent can help here.