# Best practices to prevent most of users from downloading video files from a website

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, download, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm developing a web platform for online paid courses, something like Udemy. What i want to achieve is to prevent most of users from downloading those video files or at least to make it really hard for them.

By saying prevent most of users I mean the average user, not the one with skills or with the right software tools, because I know you can't prevent all.

So I wonder which are the best practices to make it really hard for someone and not be that easy like inspect browser and copy the url from video player source.

For my point some practices i thought, are:

- Of cource using authentication system :)
- Convert video url to Blob
- Create temporary URL's

I wonder if there are some other practices to make my platform more secure.

Also I forgot to mention that we are using Amazon AWS S3 file storage, to store and get our video files, I mention this because I don't know if Amazon offers a "more secure" way to get a file from their cloud.

Comment: Implement DRM via Encrypted Media Extensions.

Comment: if you're using S3 you can restrict requests to a domain - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471661/restrict-s3-object-access-to-requests-from-a-specific-domain/14472726#14472726 - it's not a complete solution (as without DRM anything the browser can see can be downloaded) but it's a quick first step to make it harder.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thank you very much, i'll give a try :)